# Making better sense of probability graphs

Tags: probability

I obtain Figure 1, which shows the probability that a certain event will take place based on the *min threshold strain* (X-value). However, clearly the graph is hard to gather any info from. I then add up the probabilities in tiny intervals of the X-values. After that I divide each of the Y values by the sum of the Y values and it gives me Figure 2. I was wondering if what I have done is meaningful at all?

Is there some way by which I could make Graph 1 slightly better and possibly try to gather some information from it?

*There is no clear purpose behind this method. I am just trying to gather some useful information from the data that makes up Figure 1.*

Thanks

[image]

Figure including loess regression method.

[image]

**Edit**: (Discarding values very close to 1 and 0)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first graph can be improved a lot with some basic changes: 1) Put the tick marks outside the box instead of inside  2) Make sure the box does not overlap data points. (Good software ought to do this for you - `R` does, as does `SAS`).

Then you could add a smoothed line to the plot - loess or a spline for example - to see what pattern there is (again, this is easy with either `R` or `SAS` or probably other programs as well, but those are the two I know).

The second graph - I am not sure why you did what you did, but it looks like you tried to do something like loess on your own.

But, looking at the first graph, one reason it is hard to find information there is that the relationship is quite weak and there are many y = 0 and y = 1.

Comment: Thank you. I was just wondering what you mean by putting the tick marks outside the box. How could I look to pace the points outside the box?

Comment: What software did you use?

Comment: I don't know how Matlab does things, but if this is the default, then it is terrible.

Comment: May I ask what you would suggest I do Statistics wise? I could then try to implement that in Matlab?

Comment: See my answer for what I suggest

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I didn't fully understand what you meant by putting the tick marks _outside the box_ and by _make sure the box does not overlap data points_ though. I'm an amateur in Statistics and was wondering if you would mind elucidating these points? Thanks.

Comment: The tick marks are the little lines next to numbers on the two axes. They should stick outward (toward the numbers) not inward (toward the data).  The box itself is just, well... the box. But the way you have it, the points at y = 0 and y = 1 are right on top of the bottom and top borders of the box, making it harder to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks again. I've added a new Figure that includes the Loess regression technique. I wasn't able to change the direction of the ticks unfortunately, as I don't think there is such a feature available in Matlab. I just wanted to get your thoughts on this graph if possible.

Comment: Sorry, but that is much too bumpy a curve; you need to adjust the smoothing parameter.  And, if it is really the case that Matlab can't put tick marks on the outside (I would ask a Matlab expert) then I'd consider switching programs.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I will get rid of the elements that are turning out to be 0 or 1 and will try and make sense of the rest of the data as even adjusting the smoothing parameter doesn't appear to result in an even remotely smooth plot.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I've carried out the procedure I described in the previous comment and have now obtained the new graph I have added above. Would you mind sharing your thoughts on this one? Thanks.

Comment: That's better, although most programs (SAS, R) let you make smoother lines.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure with a bit more tinkering I could improve the smoothness of the lines. Is there much information I could now obtain from this graph?

Comment: It looks like there is basically no relationship between the two things.